# Jquery trouble randomly selecting divs in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of 9 divs nested in columns of three. When the grid (`#left`) is clicked , 2 divs from the middle row, `row="1"` should have the class `.show` randomly applied to it, in the column where the no class was applied the div on the bottom row, `row="2"` should have the class '.show' applied. The attached picture shows the possible random outcomes. The same outcome should never appear consecutively.

I attached a code snippet of my code, currently, my index selection is not working as desired and I have struggled to find the reason why.

[image: mock-up of wanted outcomes]

```js
var obj = {
  bindEvents: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $('#left').on("click", $.proxy(_this.interaction, _this));
  },
  interaction: function() {
    var selector = this.randomGenerator(0, 3);
    console.log('selector = ' + selector());
    var $midRow = $('#left').find('div[row=1]');
    var $bottomRow = $('#left').find('div[row=2]');
            
    $midRow.removeClass('show');
    $bottomRow.removeClass('show');
    $midRow.not(':eq(' + selector() + ')').addClass('show');
    $bottomRow.eq(selector()).addClass('show');
  },
  randomGenerator: function(min, max) {
    var last;
    console.log('last = ' + last);

    return function () {
      var random;
      do {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
      } while (random === last);
        last = random;
        return random;
      };
    },
}
obj.bindEvents();
```

```css
#left {
  display: flex;
}
div[row] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.show {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
    <div col="0">
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div col="1">
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div col="2">
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass any element to the functions.
There is no `this`... You have to provide it.

**EDIT**
When you call `selector()`, you are aware that it is a function... And that a new number is produced each time you call the function.

If you want the same "number" to be used in both `.eq()` statement, run the function just once and keep the number in a variable.

See changes in code.

```js
var obj = {
  bindEvents: function(el) {  // pass an element!
    //var _this = this;
    //$('#left').on("click", $.proxy(_this.interaction, _this));
    el.on("click", $.proxy(obj.interaction(el), el));   // Call the obj function.
  },
  interaction: function(el) {  // pass an element again!
    var selector = obj.randomGenerator(0, 3);   // Call the obj function.
    

    // Get a number
    var number = selector();
    console.log('selector = ' + number);

    var $midRow = $('#left').find('div[row=1]');
    var $bottomRow = $('#left').find('div[row=2]');
            
    $midRow.removeClass('show');
    $bottomRow.removeClass('show');
    $midRow.not(':eq(' + number + ')').addClass('show');
    $bottomRow.eq(number).addClass('show');
  },
  randomGenerator: function(min, max) {
    var last;
    console.log('last = ' + last);

    return function () {
      var random;
      do {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
      } while (random === last);
        last = random;
        return random;
      };
    },
}
obj.bindEvents($("#left"));
```

```css
#left {
  display: flex;
}
div[row] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.show {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
    <div col="0">
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div col="1">
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div col="2">
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply but I'm not sure this addresses the problem. The problem seems to be with the `randomGenerator` function and selection of the divs to add/remove `.show`  to/from

Comment: I edited... I didn't see this subtility in the expected result.